# Using ffmpeg inside batch for-loop disables use of ANSI Escape colors

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, colors

I am trying to use ESC codes to add coloring of text in a script to do batch processing of video files in a filelist.

In below code line 29, the ffmpeg code, is causing the later coloring to cancel. If I remove ffmpeg code all coloring works perfect. Please, if anyone can see where the problem is.

```
@echo off
REM Change the console encoding to UTF-8 (for Nordic characters).
chcp 65001
set filelist=%1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Define ESC escape character
for /f %%d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%%d")

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%filelist%") do (

    set Bytes=%%~za
    set MB=!Bytes:~0,-6!

    set Timestamp=%%~ta
    set TSYYYY=!Timestamp:~6,4!
    set TSYY=!Timestamp:~8,2!
    set TSMM=!Timestamp:~3,2!
    set TSDD=!Timestamp:~0,2!
    set TSHR=!Timestamp:~11,2!
    set TSMIN=!Timestamp:~14,2!

    set TSDato=!TSYY!!TSMM!!TSDD!
    set TSTid=!TSHR!!TSMIN!
    
    echo !ESC![33mConvert and compress !Bytes! Bytes sized %%~xa file to .MP4!ESC![0m
    REM Problem area. Below ffmpeg command cancels using ESC color codes. If REMed out, coloring works perfectly.
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -i "%%~da%%~pa%%~na%%~xa" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "%%~da%%~pa%%~na_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4"
    
    REM Clean up. If new file created, delete original file
    if exist "%%~da%%~pa%%~na_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4" (del "%%~da%%~pa%%~na%%~xa")
    
    echo !ESC![42mSummary!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![34mInputfile="%%~a"!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![32mOutputfile="%%~da%%~pa%%~na_!TSDato!-!TSTid!.mp4"!ESC![0m
    echo !ESC![42mFile "%%~na" optimisation complete!ESC![0m
    pause
)

echo.
echo All files optimised!
```

Comment: Hello, mistake number 1: using batch for such tasks. Which terminal is this tested in? Did you try using colors after running that ffmpeg command in the same terminal?

Comment: Thanks,@Destroy666, I get the point about using batch for this task. Need to learn Python, I guess, or what would be your own preference?
I use normal cmd window in Windows 10. Sorry, I do not understand your last question. I will try to add a screenshot here to show what's happening.

Comment: Edit: Oh no, when I tried the script on another computer, the colors were fine. Now I am really puzzled why it doesn't work on the first computer...

Comment: E.g. just PowerShell - it's 2024, even PS 7 has existed for years now. My last question is, reworded: if you run the faulty ffmpeg command in terminal where you're running the script, then you try to change colors there in any way, does it work? And now one more as you mentioned machine difference - which versions of ffmpeg do both machines have?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and efforts, Destroy666. As @Io-oI found the actual culprit, I will settle with that, but thanks again for putting me on the right track :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Change the console encoding to UTF-8 (for Nordic characters).
chcp 65001 | echo/

set "_ffflag#2=-vcodec libx265 -crf 28"
set "_ffflag#1=-y -hide_banner -v error -stats -i"
set "_ffmpeg=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

REM Define ESC escape character $E
for /f skip^=4 %%e in =;(' 
       echo;prompt;$E^|cmd.exe
     ');= do echo/ & set "_$E=%%~e"

for %%a in =;("%~1");= do =;(
    
     set "_Bytes=%%~za"
     set "_MB=!_Bytes:~0,-6!"
     
     set "_Timestamp=%%~ta"
     set "_TSYYYY=!_Timestamp:~6,4!"
     set "_TSYY=!_Timestamp:~8,2!"
     set "_TSMM=!_Timestamp:~3,2!"
     set "_TSDD=!_Timestamp:~0,2!"
     set "_TSHR=!_Timestamp:~11,2!"
     set "_TSMIN=!_Timestamp:~14,2!"
     
     set "_TSDato=!_TSYY!!_TSMM!!_TSDD!"
     set "_TSTid=!_TSHR!!_TSMIN!"
     
     echo %_$E%[33mConvert and compress !_Bytes! Bytes sized %%~xa file to .MP4%_$E%[0m
     REM Problem area. Below ffmpeg command cancels using ESC color codes. If REMed out, coloring works perfectly.
     "%ComSpec%" /v:on /e:on /q /s /c ""%_ffmpeg%" %_ffflag#1% "%%~fa" %_ffflag#2% "%%~dpna_!_TSDato!-!_TSTid!.mp4"
     chcp 65001 | echo/
      
     REM Clean up. If new file created, delete original file
     2>nul del /q "%%~fa"
      
     echo %_$E%[42mSummary%_$E%[0m
     echo %_$E%[34mInputfile="%%~a"%_$E%[0m
     echo %_$E%[32mOutputfile="%%~dpna_!_TSDato!-!_TSTid!.mp4"%_$E%[0m
     echo %_$E%[42mFile "%%~na" optimisation complete%_$E%[0m
    
    );=

timeout -1 | =;( echo. & echo All files optimised! );= & endlocal
```

---

Some programs change the chcp internally during execution and do not return to defining the active chcp before this execution/change.

Please note that I am not claiming that this is the causing (your) problem and I am not disregarding some other cause too, but if after running ffmpeg, you activate chcp 65001 again, it may also work, since in my tests the problem was resolved here.

I'm on Windows 10, the same problem occurred, and this way it was resolved. Please let me know if it solved it for you.

Comment: OMG (pardon my French)! The console command (chcp 65001) after ffmpeg did the trick!!! Can't believe it. Wow. A million thanks to you!
And thanks also for tidying up the rest of the code. Greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: For the record, need to add that I needed to add the whole code (chcp 65001 | echo/) after ffmpeg, i.e. not only the first part.

Comment: @Fjorstut Thank you for testing and reporting the positive result!